# Mathematica generating 'incorrect' Cuboids

Tags: geometric-transform, polyhedra, findinstance

Mathematica 13.1 for some reason gives an error for the following code:

```
FindInstance[{x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}][Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 3/2}]], {x, y, z}]
```

The problem as far as I can see is that `ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}][Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 3/2}]]` resolves as `Cuboid[{-1/2,-1/2,-1/2},{1/2,1/2,-3/2}]`, which is a problem for `FindInstance` because the `z` coordinates are not in the correct order (it should output `Cuboid[{-1/2,-1/2,-3/2},{1/2,1/2,-1/2}]` instead).

('Strangely' enough, `Graphics3D` has no problem with this Cuboid with coordinates in the wrong order.)

Is this a bug? And how do I handle cases like these where `Cuboid`s are incorrectly generated? I want to test whether or not two cubes (not necessarily axis-aligned) intersect using the code

```
intersectQ[cb1_?RegionQ, cb2_?RegionQ] := 
 If[FindInstance[{x, y, z} \[Element] cb1 && {x, y, z} \[Element] cb2, {x, y, z}] == {}, False, True]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegionMember` work.

```
reg = ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}][
   Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 3/2}]];
pts = {x, y, z} /. 
  FindInstance[RegionMember[reg]@{x, y, z}, {x, y, z}, 10]
Graphics3D[{{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[pts]}, Opacity[.5], 
  reg}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]